# Not able to add components to JApplet

Tags: java, japplet

I'm trying to understand how JApplet work. I've worked with JFrame before and I've got it working but I'm trying to create the same porgrams but in JApplet without any success.

I Know there is something wrong with this code but I don't know what:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

//Importerar swing biblioteket då det behövs för att skapa användargränssnitt.
import javax.swing.*;

public class BrevApplet extends JApplet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init(){
    JButton performCalculation = new JButton("Beräkna");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(200, 200);
    textArea.setText("dfgdgdgdfdgdfg");

    performCalculation.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int kostnad = 0; // Initialiserar en variabel vars värde kommer att ändra beroende på brevets vikt.
            int gram = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            String message;
            //If selektion som kollar värdet som användaren angav och ger variabel kostnad rätt värde.
            //om antal gram överskrider 2000 så anger man en sträng som informerar användaren om att
            //brevet räknas som paket. Därefter så skapar men en dialogruta som skriver ut priset.
            if(gram < 2001){
                if(gram < 21){
                    kostnad = 6;
                } else if(gram > 20 && gram < 101){
                    kostnad = 12;
                } else if(gram > 100 && gram < 251){
                    kostnad = 24;
                } else if(gram > 250 && gram < 501){
                    kostnad = 36;
                } else if(gram > 500 && gram < 1001){
                    kostnad = 48;
                } else if(gram > 1000 && gram < 2001){
                    kostnad = 72;
                }
                message = "Pris: " + kostnad;
            } else {
                message = "Brev över 2000g räknas som paket.";
            }
            textArea.setText(message);
        }

    });

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    panel1.add(textField);
    panel1.add(performCalculation);
    panel1.add(textArea);
    panel1.setOpaque(true);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.green);
    panel1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20));
    add(panel1);
}
}
```

This produces this result:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is that you enter amount gram a letter wiegh and the cost will be calculated and displayed in a JTextArea. But the JTextArea is not even showing.

Comment: Doing this assignment for my programing class. I've talked to my teacher about applets and them being outdated but its required that you port your small programs to applet aswell. So I'm trying to do it minimal.

Comment: Seriously?  They need to be sacked..  Here is a 'copy/paste' comment that I *avoided* offering in the first comment. -- Why code an applet?  *If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).*  --  So 1) ***Why*** the 'applet' requirement?  and.. 2) Did you know that an applet can easily launch a frame?  -- That latter part is important if the teacher wants an applet simply for their own lazy convenience (and has no understanding of JWS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(200, 200);
```

To:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 5);
```

..and see if it works for you.  Those integers in the constructor refer to columns & rows, *not* pixels!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted & hope your strategy works to change the mind of the teacher.  :)